# Datetimepicker - having troubles understanding the code

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, datetimepicker

I was reviewing my old piece of code i have used to unfinished project, and i can't really make sense of part of it, could you help me understand it? I'm using datetimepicker from http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/ that supports jQuery UI date picker. Here's the code (it's the onSelect event code that i don't understand):

```
    $(function() {
    var dates = $( "#from, #to" ).datetimepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
            var option = this.id == "from" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
                instance = $( this ).data( "datepicker" ),
                date = $.datepicker.parseDate(
                    instance.settings.dateFormat ||
                    $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat,
                    selectedDate, instance.settings );
            dates.not( this ).datepicker( "option", option, date );
        },
        });
    });
```

Comment: I know it's purpose is to block the from field from making dates greater than ,,to'' fields avilable. Altho I'm using datetimepicker, when i change datetime in ,,to" field, my from field appears as todays date (without time tho)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not wrong. There are 2 element `#from and #to` where if user select date value on `#from` element then the jquery function will determine selected value as `minDate` of #to element.
If user select date value for #to, then function will determine `maxDate` of #from as selected date given.

As summary, the function is to determine `minDate` or `maxDate` of element by selected another element.

```
var option = this.id == "from" ? "minDate" : "maxDate", //determine datepicker based on elemen selected
                instance = $( this ).data( "datepicker" ),
                date = $.datepicker.parseDate(
                    instance.settings.dateFormat ||
                    $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat,
                    selectedDate, instance.settings );  // retrieve selected datepicker data 
            dates.not( this ).datepicker( "option", option, date );  //select another of this element then set minDate or maxDate of datepicker data into the element
```